# VS 2013 in debug mode opens full screen file browser

Tags: wpf

After normal behaviour so far after a recent Win 10 upgrade earlier today one of my wpf projects has started to open the file browser in full screen mode when running in debug.  The minimise and restore down buttons are missing and it is not possible to change the window size using the resizing handles.

No changes have been made to the code that opens the file browser and it has been running with no issues in this and similar projects.

Of course it doesn't affect the functionality but is a real nuisance as it obscures all other open windows on a large monitor.

So far as I can tell this only happens is VS 2013 in debug mode.